# Prepositional phrase with に and verb 感じられる

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances, particles, usage

"界王神界にまでエネルギーが感じられるほど強大な力を開放し"

In this phrase, would it to be correct to say the prepositional phrase "界王神界に" connects to the object of the verb "エネルギー" or the subject of the verb (there isn't really any defined one, I guess "you" or something like that suffices). In other words, is it referring to the energy being in the Kaioshinkai, or that "you" are in the Kaioshinkai?

https://www.tsm.toyama.toyama.jp/?tid=103216

７月の金星は宵の明星として、夕方の西の空に見えます。

For example, in this sentence with an identical sentence structure, not unlike English, the prepositional phrase "夕方の西の空に" connects to the object of "見えます", "金星", and refers to Venus being in the western sky, not the subject, who's observing Venus in that location. Is the above phrase a similar case?

Comment: 感じられる is passive of 感じる=*to feel*, so it's *to be felt*. Thus the subject is エネルギー.

Comment: Thank for the response :D. So just to clarify, in that case it'd be "in the Kaioshinkai" would be referring to the energy?

Answer (score 1):

エネルギー is a **noun** meaning "energy", not a verb. The next **verb** after 界王神界に is 感じられる (the passive form of 感じる), which is what it connects to.

- エネルギー
  energy
- エネルギーが感じられる
  energy is felt
- 界王神界にまでエネルギーが感じられる
  energy is felt even in the realm of Supreme Kai
- 界王神界にまでエネルギーが感じられるほど強大な力を開放し
  unleashing an immense power to the point where energy is felt even in the realm of Supreme Kai, ...
  unleashing a power so immense that its energy is felt even in the realm of Supreme Kai, ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply :). Yeah, I misworded the original question terribly and had misinterpreted エネルギー to be the object here, my badd.


If I may ask for one little clarification, the phrase " energy is felt in the realm of the Supreme Kai", is it worded as saying tha the energy itself being in the Supreme Kai realm and hence being felt here (similar to saying like "feel it in the air" or "see it in the sky", or referring to the speaker feeling it from the Kaioshin Realm?